# changing meta search parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, meta-search

Index action

```
@search = Project.search(params[:search])
@projects = @search.order('created_at desc').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 100)
@total_projects = Project.count
respond_to do |format|
  format.html 
  format.mobile
  format.json { render :json => @projects }
end
```

if `params[:search][:stage_in]` exists and it's equal to "time_end" I want to change it like this `params[:search][:stage_in] == "started"` and it can work with @search

Answer (score 0):

I'd make a separate method to do this for you just for cleanliness. Also is that last part suppose to be a '=='?:

```
@search = Project.search(search_params(params))
@projects = @search.order('created_at desc').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 100)
@total_projects = Project.count
respond_to do |format|
  format.html 
  format.mobile
  format.json { render :json => @projects }
end  

def search_params(params)
  params[:search][:stage_in] = "started" if params[:search][:stage_in] == "time_end"
  params
end
```